# ESRI CityEngine 3D model to convert into CityGML

Tags: 3d, converters, arcgis, esri

I have found a tutorial converting the 3DCIM into CityGML. I really would like to convert our 3D models from Esri CityEngine into CityGML format. Some functions in the tutorial are not clear to me and I think there are other things missing in the toturial. I am refering to [this tutorial](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/3d/3d-cities/3d-city-base-layers/introduction-to-3d-city.htm). 
I would like to understand clearly what 3DCIM and CityGML is. Is 3DCIM a .gdb format? and CityGML .gml format?

Another thing, the **SchemaGenerator** in the tools doesn't execute. Even the **Validate CityGML files** tool does not execute. Is there any other tool that could convert Esri CityEngine 3D buildings into CityGML? Any solutions for this is really welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this tool succesfully regarding Buildings (LoD2, LoD3 and LoD4). Try to execute the SchemaGenerator via Arcmap (not via ArcCatalog). Moreover, in order to understand better how to fill the fields of feature class, it is better to  import a citygml into your file GDB.

So,

1)Generate your schema via ArcMap

2) import a citygml file into your file GDB
and see how its work.